# TFS WIQL Query condition with item's parent field

Tags: tfs, wiql

I need to query that hierarchical structure:

- Feature 1

  - Feature 2

    - PBI 1 - Title A

      - PBI 2 - Title X
  - Feature 3

    - PBI 2

I want to get Feature 1 and under Feature 1 I check its child items by child item title and also I want to get this child item's items due to their title. Is it possible to write something like that? Basically I need a recursive query down to `up.WorkItem.Title='something'` and `WorkItem.Parent.Title='something'`.

```
SELECT * FROM WorkItemLinks           
WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = @project 
AND [Source].[System.WorkItemType] In('Feature','Product Backlog Item') 
AND [Source].[System.State] <> '' 
AND [Source].[System.Title] = 'Feature1') 
AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') 
AND ( [Target].[System.State] = 'New'
AND [Target].[System.WorkItemType] In('Feature','Product Backlog Item') 
AND ( [Target].[System.Title] = 'Title A' or **[Target].[System.Title].Parent='Feature2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Tree Query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/wiql#GetworkitemsAtreequery) to achieve this.

A easy way to do this is creating the query directly in the web portal. A simple example like following:
[image]

And you can check the WIQL code for the query via [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/queries#GetaqueryorfolderHierarchicalquerywithexpandedclauses) if you want to use it:
[image]

Update:
You can add a filter in "Filters for linked work items" and use "Or" for the two filters as following if you want "Workitem.Title=PB1 or WorkItem.Parent.Title =Feature":
[image]

Comment: Yes I can take hiercial like that but my problem is conditional searching,I want to like,if Workitem.Title=PB1 or WorkItem.Parent.Title =Feature2, ,in Feature1 childs

Comment: @Bilgehan If you want "Workitem.Title=PB1 or WorkItem.Parent.Title =Feature2", you can add a filter in "Filters for linked work items" and use "Or" for the two filters. See my updated answer. But if you want "Workitem.Title=PB1 and WorkItem.Parent.Title =Feature", there is any way to do this for now.

Comment: Hi Eddie,I want to do "Workitem.Title=PB1 and WorkItem.Parent.Title =Feature